# Low Index Subgroups in GAP

Tags: finite-fields, gap

I want to find an algorithm for constructing a coset table for all subgroups of index 14 of triangle group (2,3,7) by using Low index subgroups.

for this I am making a program like this.

f:=FreeGroup(2);

g:=f/[f.1^2,f.2^3,(f.1*f.2)^7];

LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup(g,14);
where 14 is the index of the subgroup in g. However, it gives me Group() Could any one help me finding such an algorithm for.

Comment: I am surprised, why doesn't it showing to me. ok. If you get this, May I ask how I can find the list of generators for one the index in these list?

Comment: I am surprised it gives me an answer with 14 set list like  Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>),
  Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>),
  Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>),
  Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>),
  Group(<fp, no generators known>), Group(<fp, no generators known>) ]

Comment: Could you please copy your results here? so that I could check where is the mistake or what is missing?

Comment: I get the same output as yours, then I ask for the indices and get the list above.

Comment: What the command you used to find indices? Is it Indices(last);

Comment: `no generators known` in the output is legitimate in this context. `GeneratorsOfGroup` may be used to display them.

Comment: Thanks to all for your supporting replies. This really find me helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code finds the 9 conjugacy classes of subgroups of index 14, and displays the coset table of the first one. The rows are $f_1, f_1^{-1}, f_2, f_2^{-1}$. For completed coset tables, the inverses are not very interesting, but they can be very useful for incomplete coset tables. I also include the coset table rows written as permutations, since that seems more useful to me.

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup(2);;
gap> g:=f/[f.1^2,f.2^3,(f.1*f.2)^7];;
gap> hs:=Filtered(LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup(g,14),h->Index(g,h)=14);; Size(hs);
9
gap> PrintArray( CosetTable( g, hs[1] ) ) ;;
[ [   1,   2,   4,   3,   7,   8,   5,   6,  12,  13,  14,   9,  10,  11 ],
  [   1,   2,   4,   3,   7,   8,   5,   6,  12,  13,  14,   9,  10,  11 ],
  [   2,   3,   1,   5,   6,   4,   9,  11,  10,   7,  12,   8,  13,  14 ],
  [   3,   1,   2,   6,   4,   5,  10,  12,   7,   9,   8,  11,  13,  14 ] ]
gap> List( CosetTable( g, hs[1] ){[1,3]}, PermList );
[ (3,4)(5,7)(6,8)(9,12)(10,13)(11,14), (1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,9,10)(8,11,12) ]
```

Comment: I am running the same program without Filtered. It gives me successful results, can I ask why are you using Filtered operation with it?

Comment: is last statement why are you using {[1,3]}, what does that mean?

Comment: Filtered removes bad items from a list. In this case, I only want subgroups whose index is exactly 14, not ≤ 14.  `Index(g,h)=14`  In the last line, I don't really care about rows 2 and 4 (the inverse rows), so I ask for rows 1 and 3 with `{[1,3]}`.